# Простейший сервер на c++

Tags: c++, сервер

Не биндит порт.Не знаю в чем проблема....
Вот Код

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<resolv.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
     struct sockaddr_in sock;
     int fd;
     int sd;
     memset(&sock,0,sizeof(sock));
     char msg[300];
     sock.sin_family = PF_INET;
     sock.sin_port = htons(565);
     sock.sin_addr.s_addr = 0; //принимаем подключения на все IP
      if((fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1 )
      {
          fprintf(stderr,"Can't open socket\n");
      }
      if ( bind(fd,(sockaddr *)&sock,sizeof(sock)) == -1 )
      {
          fprintf(stderr,"Can't bind\n");
          exit(0);
      }
      listen(fd,0x100);
     sockaddr_in client_addr;
     int client_addr_size = sizeof (client_addr);
     while( (sd = accept(fd,(sockaddr*)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)&client_addr_size)) !=-1 )
     {
       send(sd,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
       memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
       recv(fd,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
       printf("%s\n",msg);
     }
     close(fd);
     close(sd);
     scanf("%i",&sd);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классика - нельзя хватать порты с номером < 1024. Они специальные, их может трогать только суперпользователь.

Comment: Вы правы! Не учел это,спасибо.)

Comment: @Max, если ответ верный и удовлетворяет Вас, тогда примите его как «ответ». Для этого нужно нажать на галочку рядом с ответом

Comment: Конечно! Ребят, подскажите, а какие книги из современных можно почитать по сетевому программированию под Unix? Сейчас читаю Уолтона...

Comment: @Max это тут уже оффтопик, но читайте Снейдера  (Эффетивное программирование TCP/IP) и Танненбаума (Компьютерные сети)